# What is the part of speech of “a little” in these sentences?

Tags: parts-of-speech

Here are my guess:

- I can speak English a little. (adverb)
- I can speak a little English. (here “a little” can be adjective describing English or it can be adverb describing speak)

Comment: If there is a language there, 'a little' will describe how much can you speak in that language because if you want to describe how much you can speak, don't bother putting a language there.

Answer (score 1):

I'd agree in the first case, *little* is used as an adverb.

In the second example,

> I can speak a little English.

it's an adjective. Consider the following:

> I can speak a little English and a little Xhosa.

Here it is made clear that each *little* is referring to each (proper) noun.

Of course, just to confuse the issue, *little* could even be a noun.

> "Would you like some sherbet?"
>
> "I'd like a little."